# How do I automate a daily download from an SFTP server? Currently trying Power Automate

Tags: sftp, automation

I am trying to use power automate to automate a daily process of connecting to a sftp, downloading files onto my local drive. My biggest issue is I am unable to whitelist all of the IP addresses associated with Microsoft and can only connect using the IP address from my office. I attempted going around this by using power automate's CMD functionality but I am unable to insert the password doing this. So my problem has two different paths to the same result and was wondering if either are possible, and if so how to do it.

1. Connect to SFTP using power automate using my local IP address
2. Connect to SFTP using the CMD/terminal functionality within Power Automate and give commands through that.

If there is another solution using task scheduler or something else, I am very open to all and any suggestions.

Comment: *but I am unable to insert the password doing this*  Can you use SSH keys, so you don't need a password.  And anyone who says using keys is less secure than a password can be safely ignored as they've just demonstrated utter incompetence, especially if they work in any security-related field.

Answer (score 1):

ssh support in MS-Windows is minimal.

I believe that you may be able to solve your problem with pscp - this comes as part of the PuTTy distribution. You can specify a "keyboard interactive" password on the command line or (maybe?) stored in the registry. WinSCP can also run a script provided on the command line and use a password from the arguments or stored config.